# Changing the width of a button - Responsive webpage (bulma)

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am trying to make my page responsive and I would like in the mobile version of the page to change the width of a button to take up the whole width of the page. This is how the desktop version should look:
[image]

And this is the mobile version how it should look:

[image]

I can't figure out how to change my button so that it takes part all the screen width using bulma. This is my code:

```
<div className="buttons mt-6 mx-4 is-justify-content-space-between">
        <button className="button has-background-link has-text-white has-text-weight-bold" style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
          <span className="mx-4">Back</span>
        </button>
        <button className="button has-background-primary has-text-white has-text-weight-bold" style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
          <span>Go to Basket</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

I have tagged HTML, CSS and Bulma because I am not sure which of the following could solve the problem, as I am using bulma but this is an external problem to bulma reactiveness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use @media tags in CSS.

```
<style>
/* Default Styling */
.button {
    width: 300px;
}

/* Only applies if the window with is under 600px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .button {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>

<div className="buttons mt-6 mx-4 is-justify-content-space-between">
    <button className="button has-background-link has-text-white has-text-weight-bold" style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
        <span className="mx-4">Back</span>
    </button>
    <button className="button has-background-primary has-text-white has-text-weight-bold" style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
        <span>Go to Basket</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
#test {
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 50px;  // add this if you want
   max-width: 300px; // add this if  you want, adjust accordingly
}

<div className="buttons mt-6 mx-4 is-justify-content-space-between">
        <button id="test" className="button has-background-link has-text-white has-text-weight-bold" style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
          <span className="mx-4">Back</span>
        </button>
        <button id="test" className="button has-background-primary has-text-white has-text-weight-bold" style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
          <span>Go to Basket</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```